# Why is a Coulomb the charge of $6.24 \times 10^{18}$ electrons?

Tags: charge, conventions, history, si-units, metrology

Where does the $6.24 \times 10^{18}$ number come from? How was it historically derived?

I know that $1$ C $=$ $1$ A s but that just pushes the question down another step, and another and another, at some point where do these numbers actually originate and bubble up from?

Comment: Would this be better on [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definition of Ampere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101953/)

Comment: Well, apart from the historic conventions, the number stems from the value of the (low energy) electromagnetic coupling constant. It is one of the dimensionless parameters that we simply measure and can't predict using the current best framework of particle physics which is known as the standard model.

Comment: I believe that the coulomb (actually a small fraction of it) was originally defined as the charge supported by a typical ball of sulfur, at the time Coulomb made his experiments.  But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, the coulomb is an ampere-second. The ampere was historically defined to make the magnetic force per unit length between two parallel one-amp currents with a “nice” separation have a “nice” value. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere) explains (with my bolding for emphasis),

> “The ampere was originally defined as one tenth of the unit of electric current in the centimetre–gram–second system of units. That unit, now known as the abampere, was defined as the amount of current that generates a force of **two dynes per centimetre** of length between two wires **one centimetre apart**. The size of the unit was chosen so that the units derived from it in the MKSA system would be conveniently sized.”

Comment: So the modern Ampere is a tenth of the Abampere, why was Abampere not appropriate for usage? I don't understand what "The size of the unit was chosen so that the units derived from it in the MKSA system would be conveniently sized." is referring to specifically, I presume Ampere? Why was two dynes chosen?

Comment: That’s the history, not the modern definition. Modern SI units are not defined in terms of other unit systems.

Comment: An answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101953/definition-of-ampere) has an explanation for the factor of 2. I can’t vouch for it.

Comment: There is no physics in unit systems. They are completely arbitrary human conventions.

Comment: I understand they are arbitrary but I like knowing where the numbers come from, otherwise it just looks like a random number I could pull out of a hat, it helps to know why certain numbers were chosen for whatever convenient reasons in whatever contexts in whatever time period

Comment: I have no idea why they didn’t just adopt the abampere, since it differed by only a factor of 10.